# How to disable web security using selenium code for IE and Firefox

Tags: selenium, browser, selenium-webdriver, cross-browser, webbrowser-control

Written below code for chrome to disable web security

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Eclipse\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
/*options.addArguments("test-type");
options.addArgument("--start-maximized");*/
options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
/* options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");*/
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary","D:/Eclipse/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

But I want to disable same for FF and IE.